# How to add "upload profile picture" to the front end of my site?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm finding it hard to find a plugin that allows an upload profile picture in the front end of my website. It would be ideal if i could have a code that i input that creates an "upload profile pictures" as i need it for an ID.

Please could someone tell me how this is done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19064/frontend-image-uploading-from-edit-profile-page-goldenapples

Comment: Can you tell which platform are you using ?

Comment: wordpress @MaheshGareja

Comment: try this https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/